# How to overlay a glass pane over a panel (div) in GWT

Tags: java, user-interface, gwt

I am building an "Edit" widget. To edit a data entity.

I want to add auto save to this and while the auto save is happening I want the edit panel to be disabled and overlayed with "glass panel"... in other words a translucent panel with a message saying.. "saving".

How do I do overlay a panel with a glass pane?

I've seen [GlassPanel](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/GlassPanel) from gwt incubation but it is very old so I'm hoping for something bit more recent and bit more elegant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that might help you is the [`PopupPanel`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html) which inherently supports a glass panel that may be used as you want.

So, have your "Saving" message dialog extend `PopupPanel` and `.setGlassEnabled( true )` and you should be fine.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks. that's a good idea and I've done that. 

It would be nice though to be able to only glass the editor control and not the whole screen...